# Installed Anaconda to macOS that has Python2.7 and 3.7. Pandas only importing to 2.7; how can I import to 3.7?

Tags: python, pandas, macos, import, sublimetext3

New to coding; I just downloaded the full Anaconda package for Python 3.7 onto my Mac. However, I can't successfully import Pandas into my program on SublimeText when running my Python3.7 build. It DOES work though, when I change the build to Python 2.7. Any idea how I can get it to properly import when running 3.7 on SublimeText? I'd just like to be able to execute the code within Sublime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall python 2.7. Unless you use it, its better to uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a shot today!